# In Red Dead Redemption, can I kill people near the end when coming out of the barn?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

When I come out of the barn at the very end, for my very last stand, can I kill any of the main culprits who I'd like to exact revenge on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way you could kill any main character in the last stand as the only ones showing there are generic army characters.

Comment: How many can you kill?

Comment: you can Kill as many as your skills let you!
One thing to consider is that if you complete ALL survivalist challenges your Dead Eye meter will increase ... I have not tried it yet but -I think- it is enough to kill all of them ... but -I don't think- this will change the ending though!

Comment: I guess there's no way to go back and do that part again unless I have an old save game :\

Comment: You can Replay any mission you want again ... just go to your menu and then select Stats > Missions ... the last mission is called : The Last Enemy to Be Destroyed. enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

To disagree with some of the other posters, [The Last Enemy That Shall Be Destroyed](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Enemy_That_Shall_Be_Destroyed) mission on the Red Dead Redemption Wiki offers the following as a possibility.

> Even though the player can shoot Edgar Ross and Archer Fordham dead in the final Dead Eye moment, Ross will still be alive in the following cutscene.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can't kill any of them straight away, but if you keep playing as Jack you will eventually duel and kill the main federal agent badguy (you need to talk to the agent at the station in Blackwater, not on the map).

Answer (score 2):

No. you cannot. Unfortunatly, there are to many soldiers around, and they are hiding behind them. Even with the Evans repeater and moonshine along with a maxed dead eye means 22 dead bodies, all soldiers. The Federal Agents do not poke their heads up until after John gets gunned down. I have done the mission twice, and neither time was able to kill anyone other than the soldiers. It is fun taking moonshine before walking out and using the Evans, and just blast as many as you can. A bit gratifying, but the mission always ends the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small chance to hide back in the barn and fight longer but you have to die to continue the game.